# How can I backup Azure Event Hub Schema Registry?

Tags: azure, avro, azure-eventhub

I'd like to start using Event Hub's schema registry but in the event that the schemas are lost or destroyed I'm unable to see a way to backup or restore them. Whilst the original schemas will be in source control, without the original ID I'm unable to link previously published events back to the original schema.

Is it possible to restore a deleted schema registry with original IDs?

Answer (score 0):

We can't recover the deleted `Event Hub` unless you configured the [Geo-disaster recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-geo-dr?tabs=portal).

As per the Microsoft Documentation,

> **Azure Schema Registry** is a feature of Event Hubs, which provides a central repository for schemas for event-driven and messaging-centric applications. It provides the flexibility for your producer and consumer applications to **exchange data without having to manage and share the schema**.

Delete fields / Delete optional fields by using the Backward compatibility / Forward compatibility stated in the [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/schema-registry-overview#backward-compatibility).

Thanks to @`Mai Ali`, response from the [Recover deleted Event Hub](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c7e1ba7d-5215-4b0d-93a2-6d6ecf21de99/recover-deleted-event-hub?forum=notificationhubs).